# How to select the every first character from mysqli database:

Tags: php, mysql, select

How to select the every first character from mysql database with different gallery name, i have that database - how to select the first image with galery name(column "gallery") img and the first image with gallery name img2?

http://prikachi.com/images/989/7212989B.png

[image]

Comment: I would not recommend saving an image in the database directly, but saving a link to the location of the image.

Comment: Why not to upload image into the database?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use-

```
LIMIT 0,1
```

with your query, so that only 1 item (first item) is fetched.

For eg:

```
SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE gallery="img2" LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Could you make an example?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first image in each gallery, then you have to GROUP BY the gallery column, and select the column you want, like:

```
SELECT gallery, min(id) from {table} GROUP BY gallery;
```

This will give you the output:

```
| gallery  |  id  |
+----------+------+
| img      |   1  |
| img2     |   2  |
```